# A chord is three notes? What do you call just two notes?

Tags: chords, chord-theory

Until very recently I'd though a chord was any group of notes played together.

However, I just heard a chord defined as "three  or more notes played together."

If this is the case, what should I call just two notes played together?

Comment: This probably answers your question: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14320/why-are-two-pitches-considered-a-chord and this might be a duplicate.

Comment: @OldJohn so basically, the person who said it was three or more was wrong?

Comment: Not necessarily wrong - some people allow 2-note chords and some people insist that a chord has three or more simultaneous notes. It is more a matter of terminology rather than right or wrong, I believe.

Comment: Note that in  geometry, a chord is a line segment (two points) on a circle.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From my experience, there is no one 'best' term for two notes played together that is universally (or near-universally) agreed-on.

**dyad** is the most specific term for a pair of pitches sounding together, but it's not commonly-used.

**interval** works for many, but others will say that is a term for the distance between the notes, rather than something that refers to the act of playing them together.

some will say that **chord** is fine for two notes, and that seems to be the case for specific usages like the term 'power chord'.

on stringed instruments one may talk about playing a **double-stop**, although that's a reference to the playing technique rather than the pure concept.

So basically, whatever term someone uses, you have license to be a bore and tell them they're wrong.

Comment: Note that a **harmonic interval** specifically means two notes at the same time, where **melodic interval** means two following each other. Though I'd argue that interval refers more to the space than the notes themselves. It depends on context.

Comment: FWIW I've heard the term *double-stop* referring to two (side-by-side) notes being played simultaneously on a diatonic harmonica (e.g. draw 4 & draw 5 played together, but maybe the term was borrowed from guitarists); also *octave*, referring to two notes being played simultaneously at an octave *interval* (e.g. draw 2 & draw 5 played together w/ tongue blocking holes 3 & 4). I guess that confirms your last point :-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug I agree that usage of 'double stop' sounds like it may be a borrowing - to 'stop' a string is to hold it down at a certain position - does 'stop' on its own mean anything in harmonica terminology? (apart from "stop playing it"!)

Comment: LOL! Pretty sure it's just borrowed. That said, [Howard Levy](https://youtu.be/fmL4RM7IA7A) wouldn't agree with "stop playing it" ;-)  check out players such as Jason Ricci, Adam Gussow, or the absolutely gorgeous [Indiara Sfair](https://youtu.be/a7-JRUyKV08)... I mean, if all you've ever heard is Bob Dylan or Steven Tyler "playing" a harp, I can see why one would want it to stop! Otherwise, harmonica is absolutely a real and complex instrument that deserves much more respect than it's getting, IMHO.

Comment: On a stringed instruments a double-stop refers to 2 strings at once, 3 strings, or 4 strings played all together as a chord  (not just 2).

Comment: @MCMastery 3 would be a triple stop ('stopping' 3 strings), and 4 a quadruple stop. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_stop; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pn4D2p2_iDM; http://imslpforums.org/viewtopic.php?t=6696

Comment: @topomorto That's actually quite odd, I've had around 6 different violin teachers and they've all called them double stops, regardless of how many notes are played. Maybe it's regional, but that wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: @MCMastery maybe a modesty thing... just because you can do a quadruple stop doesn't mean you have to shout about it? :)

Comment: @user45266 'dyad' it is then! (This question has a lot of views so perhaps we can take the credit if the word's getting more common :)

Comment: I've encountered the term 'dyad' with some frequency in jazz composition contexts. Maybe @user45266 & I have similar musical backgrounds. I wonder if some of the confusion around this term is due to triads being the most basic chord in western music. A chord with two notes doesn't have a defined chord quality in the traditional western sense, and thus some might consider it an incomplete chord. This represents a narrower interpretation of the term, of course. (I laughed aloud at this line! *"So basically, whatever term someone uses, you have license to be a bore and tell them they're wrong."*)

Comment: @jdjazz  I wonder if two-part harmony (dyadic?) is an oddly unexplored  area in music due to the triad becoming such common currency.

Comment: @topomorto That sort of ties into another recent question: I bet two-voice harmony might like to use *10ths* to effect a harmony...

Answer (score 6):

Ultimately there is no unanimous definitions for these words, so it's useful to know how they can be used.

One definition has a *chord* being three or more notes. This means that having only two notes wouldn't be a chord but would be an *interval.*

As someone else pointed out, power chords are a thing and consist of only two pitches (though they may run through several octaves). It seems entirely reasonable to call such an interval a *chord* since it is functioning as one. Which leads us to a definition based on function.

If your note aggregate under question functions as a chord in terms of voice leading and harmony then it would be a *chord* and an interval could then also be a *chord*. But, just having three notes sounding at the same time would not necessarily be a *chord* if they are not functioning as a chord re voice leading and harmony. Such a collection would just be a *note aggregate* or potentially a *cluster.*

In summary, you can define chords in terms of numbers or function. An interval is always two pitches (though they can be the same exact pitch!) and can be considered a chord in certain circumstances/definitions. Under other circumstances having three or more notes might not be considered a chord but an aggregate or cluster (or even more confusingly a *cluster chord!*)

You'll hear and witness any and all of these usages so it's good to be aware of the many different ways these terms are used.

Answer (score 2):

A Chord is what happens when you play or sing more than one note at a time. 2 note chords are called partial chords. 3 note chords spaced by thirds and fifths are called Triads. Triads are not ambiguous. e.g. CEG is an unambigous C Major triad. The idea behid so called partial chords is that thay are ambiguous. For example C and E are notes in both the C Major (CEG) and A Minor (ACE) triads. CE is a partial chord with no name.

A special case of this is so called '5' chords which do have a name. G5, for example is comp\osed of the notes G and D. It's called G5 because it contains the root G and its perfect fifth D. Since it has no third to tell whether it's Major or Minor it's still ambiguous. Rock Guitarist like these chords.

Just to be super clear: partial chords are bits of triads (usually), and Triads form the "cores" of larger chords (like Am7).

Comment: This may be how some use the terms, but it's far from universal.

Comment: Try as I may, I can't sing more than one note at a time!

Answer (score 2):

Melodic and Harmonic intervals:

> “Melodic” means played one note at a time, either ascending or descending in pitch. “Harmonic” means both notes are played together.

<sub>([source](https://www.musical-u.com/learn/5-minute-guide-to-interval-ear-training/))</sub>

Comment: Welcome to Music Stack Exchange! Please note that we have [some rules](/help/referencing) about copying content from elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @topomorto's answer you could also use "implied harmony." For example, G over B moving to E over C (all naturals) implies a G major chord going to C major even though the fifths of the chord are missing from the implied triads.

I prefer this definition which simply defines *chord* as a harmonic entity of multiple pitches (indefinite quantity.)

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_(music)

If you want to refer to one of those chords as *dyad*, *triad* etc...

- https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/polyad

Comment: Fifths are often the first notes to be omitted. Ironic for a power chord..!

Answer (score 1):

The actual answer is "An Interval." Of course, that isn't a complete explanation. An interval may appear on its own or as a representative of a chord. For example the interval C-E by itself is just a major third. In a piece of music it could stand for a C major chord, and A minor chord, depending on the voice leading. It could just be an incomplete chord. A fifth C-G can, with enough distortion be a Power Chord representing C major (or minor).

Comment: How does that work? I play power chords all the time, but never actually knew that they were such a special case. Does the distortion generate an extra pitch or something? The major or minor third? Why do you note them at the end as being something different to an interval, even though they are just two notes?

Comment: @theonlygusti distortion does indeed generate extra harmonics; whether or not you'd call them extra pitches is debatable, but a distorted open fifth can *sound* bigger than a lot more notes played without distortion.

Comment: Distortion adds overtones, both harmonic and inharmonic.  So full chords get muddy.  Single notes, fifths or octaves sound clearer.   Or you can exploit the muddiness by playing full chords and going for a 'wall of sound' thing.

Comment: The trouble with calling two notes played together an "interval" is that "interval" is usually used to mean, not the actual playing of two notes together, but the distance between two notes (specified by, say, "major third" or "5/4 ratio" or whatever).  I think it's less ambiguous to just call any two notes played together a "chord", and then further specifying what kind of chord it is (unison, octave, major third, major triad, etc.).  I doubt this will catch on, but as I said above, it doesn't really matter, as long as it's made clear what is meant.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the nomenclature is not perfectly agreed upon.  But we simply have to deal with that.  How about simply stipulating what the tones are, and not agonizing over whether it's an "interval" or a "chord".  The definitions are not going to help tell you what it "is".

Comment: The interval definitely has a definition!

Comment: @Tim - oh?  What is it?

Comment: Actually every interval has a minimum of two terms! Is that where your question emanated from?

Answer (score 0):

Harmonic interval = two notes played simultaneously.

Chord = three or more notes played simultaneously.

These definitions are universally accepted. It's physics, much like GPS triangulation; it is not possible to determine the root let alone the type of chord unless you have at least three notes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100768/discussion-between-nickgrooves-and-user45266).

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the term to describe 2 notes playing together, playing only two notes is not enough to define the "character" of the "chord". In other words, you can't say is minor or major only with 2 notes. That's why you need a third or more.

Also, remember a chord doesn't need to be played by one instrument alone, let's say one instrument is playing just harmonic intervals (2 notes playing together) and another instrument is playing a melody on the top. The points when the sounds of the 2 instrument mix together with 2 different notes creates the chords that defines the harmony of the song.

Comment: Play something like `FF` `GF` `CE` and the implied harmony is pretty strong where the final chord is `C` major with the `E` being the chord's third. And omitting the fifth isn't going to throw into question whether the final chord is an augmented are strange diminished quality. Full triads would write out the chord qualities _literally_, but two part harmony can certainly define the qualities of chords.

Comment: After a sequence of intervals you can get the harmony, although 2 notes alone you can't not. You can get harmony in the context of several instrument like my second paragraph, but also you can o do some sort of chromatic or crazy harmony (taste is relative). But with 3 notes there is no doubt what are the character of the chord.

Comment: "With 3 tones there is not doubt." Not really. Three tones `CDG` is still ambiguous. The point is that a stack of tones doesn't provide as much _meaningful_ harmonic context as movement of voices. 3 tones = a chord is basic textbook level understanding. Chords are theoretical constructions, identifiable even with chord tones not present, that's the enlightened understanding.